# how to stop overflow of div with 100% width

Tags: html

I have this example and I need to stop the blue div from overflowing (respect the padding), but I need 100% width.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>  
</div>

#container{
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    padding-left 50px;
    border : solid 1px brown;
    min-height: 400px;
    background: green;
}
#content {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    min-height: 200px;
    width:100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

pls how could I do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the width of your content, I think everything works out as you'd like?

http://jsfiddle.net/PPYQQ/

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    padding-left 50px;
    border : solid 1px brown;
    min-height: 400px;
    background: green;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Note that you can't have it both ways -- the child cannot both be 400px + 100px padding but also fill the parent which is 400px in size.

Comment: Thanks I thought, that I need 100% width to have full width div :( :)